# How to format a JSONObject Unit test to not be null?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

When I run the following unit test on the sendCommand Method, I get a null pointer exception. How do I format my JSON Object to properly Unit

My Unit test:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void shouldThrowIllegalStateExceptionOnUnknownCommand() {
        try {
            JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
            test.put("name", "UnitTest");
            test.put("payload", "{ \"example\": \"payload\" }");
            testClassObject.sendCommand(test);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to parse JSON Object Unit test" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My Method:

```
public void sendCommand(JSONObject reader) {
        try {
            String commandName = reader.getString("name");
            JSONObject data = reader.getJSONObject("payload");
            switch (commandName)
            {
                case "ValidCommand":
                    //Do Stuff
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unknown command");
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown command: " + commandName);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, " Failed to parse JSON Object / array " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My Error message:

```
Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
    java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalStateException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
```

This error message is occurring at the Switch statement of sendCommand().

Comment: Is `testClassObject` even instantiated? From what you have pasted, the nullpointer might be coming from `testClassObject.sendCommand(test);`.

Comment: You don't show where you're getting the NPE, so there's no telling why you're getting that error. Your stack trace should tell you exactly what line the error is occurring on. Also, instead of putting in a JSON string, make a second JSONObject and put that in your current object.

Comment: testClassObject is instantiated, I chose to leave this out of the code I provided.
My full stack trace shows the null pointer exception is read at the beginning of the switch statement. This showcases that "name" is never read, meaning my JSON Object is empty or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader.getJSONObject("payload")` isn't a `JSONObject` - it's a `String`

you should add this when you create you test object

```
test.put("payload", new JSONObject("{ \"example\": \"payload\" }"));
```